# What is the time complexity of Hoare's partitioning of the Quick Sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

For the algorithms course, I am asked to find the missing first element in an array consisting of sequential elements but shuffled in O(n). For example at first, the array is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. Now randomly choose 7 and remove it. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]`. Now shuffle the array `[5, 3, 10, 9, 1, 6, 2, 4, 8]`. Now the algorithm should return 7.

But,
there are some restrictions to solve the problem:

- Algorithm must use and modify partitioning part of the quicksort and must use recursion
- Must be O(n) at most

I have managed to write the code and do these operations but I am not sure if I satisfied the conditions. I've implemented the partitioning part as [Coding with John's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8eyY7dIiN4&t=634) does. But I failed to determine the time complexity of my code.

```java
static int findMissingElement(int[] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {

        if (lowIndex >= highIndex) {
            return -1;
        }

        int pivot = array[highIndex];

        int leftPointer = lowIndex;
        int rightPointer = highIndex;

        while (leftPointer < rightPointer) {

            while (array[leftPointer] <= pivot && leftPointer < rightPointer) {
                leftPointer++;
            }

            while (array[rightPointer] >= pivot && leftPointer < rightPointer) {
                rightPointer--;
            }

            swap(array, leftPointer, rightPointer);
        }

        // left pointer and right pointers are met. So swap the pivot with pointing
        // element.
        swap(array, leftPointer, highIndex);

        if (leftPointer + 1 != array[leftPointer]) {
            return leftPointer + 1;
        }

        int leftResult = findMissingElement(array, lowIndex, leftPointer - 1);

        if (leftResult != -1) {
            return leftResult;
        }

        int rightResult = findMissingElement(array, leftPointer + 1, highIndex);

        if (rightResult != -1) {
            return rightResult;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int temp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = temp;
    }
```

The output is:

```
Before: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
After shuffling and removing one element : [5, 3, 10, 9, 1, 6, 2, 4, 8]
Result: 7
```

as expected.

Comment: Partition is O(n), but you've missed an important trick in your code -- you only have to call `findMissingElement` once recursively because once you've partitioned you can tell which "half" has a missing element by looking at the size of each of the partitions. For example, if 7 is missing from 1..10 and you've partitioned with element "5" then you discover 4 smaller elements in the left partition (as expected; 1, 2, 3, 4), but only 4 elements larger than 5 (you'd expect 5 if none were missing; 6, 7, 8, 9, 10). Thus you only need to search the right-hand partition.

Comment: A second thing you've missed is that unlike regular quicksort (or quickselect), you can pick the pivot value directly without looking at any array elements. For example, if you start with 1..10, then pick the pivot 5 -- you know this will partition the array into near-halves. This insight is necessary to get "O(n) at most" -- or else you need a much more sophisticated pivot-picking approach to avoid O(n^2) worst-case with unlucky pivot choices.

Comment: What you implemented is not Hoare's partition, though it contains one ! At first sight, it does not have an O(N) behavior.

Comment: An aside: Java doesn't have pointers; a better name for your variables is `leftIndex` etc

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Hoare's partition is to move the small elements to the left and the large ones to the right, and this is done with respect to a pivot value*.

We can explain it like this, given an array to be processed:

- look for a large element, coming from the left**;
- look for a small element, coming from the right but not passing the large element that you found;
- swap them.

Now you have a shorter subarray where the partitioning condition is not guaranteed yet (it is guaranteed outside), and you can recurse on it. Recursion stops when the subarray is less than two elements long.

---

*Contrary to a common belief, there is no need to process the pivot element in a special way; Hoare's partition will move it naturally.

**A key ingredient of the algorithm is that you must always be able to find at least one small and at least one large element. This is why non-strict comparisons to the pivot value are mandated.